# How to add column to data-bound control in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms

Our app has a form that uses a BindingSource with a DataGridView. I've been tasked with adding a column. I don't know where to begin.

(In my own programming, I avoid black boxes that I don't understand.)

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridView control allows you to use auto generated columns or define your own. I'm using a DataGridView with columns I've defined, so I don't know if you can add a column if it's set to auto generate them (as might be the case for your data bound DataGridView).

The steps would be:

```
 dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
 //create column
 DataGridViewTextBoxColumn nameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
 nameColumn.Name = "Name";
 nameColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
 nameColumn.HeaderText = "Action";
 nameColumn.Width = 140;
 nameColumn.FillWeight = 25;
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
 dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].ReadOnly = true;
```

If you create all columns manually, add them the same way and then add the binding info.